# Aws Signing request using node/Aws4

Tags: amazon-web-services, signing

My use-case is: We have different api's which user hit to get data. Currently user has to send the Key in authorization header. Our api then verify the key. Now requirement is instead of sending key user will send signature and keyIdentifier in header. Our api then get the key against this identifier from KMS and again create signature. and if both are same request request will be proceed otherwise denied.

```
let opt={
             host: "1hf7rp3nqe.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
             method: "GET",
             url: `https://a23t56yu.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/devices`,      
             path: "/test/users",
             timestamp: "20120215"
          }


     let req=aws4.sign(opt, {accessKeyId: "sample", secretAccessKey: '7CDLnmk9'});
```

Comment: The signature is generated using not only accessKeyId and secretAccessKey. There are other random parameters generated, such as nonce and timestamp, and used to generate the signature. That's why there are never the same signatures between two API calls.

Comment: then how we verify that the signature is valid in request header?. In my case user only send identifier and signature in header. and my api then get key from KMS against that identifier and again create signature with this key and have to compare this signature with the request header signature. If both match then proceed otherwise denied.

Comment: @Boom it isn't clear what you are really trying to do, here, but *your code* should not be in a position where it needs to verify a signature.  If you are in possession of a signed request, you should just be *using* it and the target service should allow or deny accordingly.  Please edit the question to express, more clearly, the purpose of the second API needing to actually validate the signature generated by the first API, and now these components interact.

Comment: if you want to compare the signature generated by the user and the signature generated using KMS then you first need to know how user is generating the signature and try to generate the signature using the same way in your code using KMS and compare them.

Comment: @Michael, i edited the requirement, hopefully its more clear now

Comment: @Chetan, i need to create signature by using amazon signv4. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html. By using this is it possible to create sign by just one attribute key?

Comment: That documentation pretty much explains what to do step by step.  Did you try them? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html#sig-v4-examples-using-sdk-dotnet

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateSignatureInCSharp.html

Comment: @Chetan yes i review these.I have to implement in Nodejs

Comment: If the logic is clear to you, is it not possible to write NodeJS code for the same logic?

Comment: Yes its possible, i am implementing it. Thanks for you suggestions.